# Sencha Touch Container with flexible width and preserving form factor

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need a Sencha Touch Container that, once I set a width for it (fixed or in percent of the parent), automatically calculates its height to keep a given form factor, even when screen is rotated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a listener to the panel and on resize event calculate the new height based on the width?

Comment: @PeterKellner I guess that is the way to go, if you want to elaborate an answer I would be glad to accept it, else I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @PeterKellner suggestion of leveraging the `resize` event, it turned out it was easier than I thought implementing such a component:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.ux.AutoResizeComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'autoresizecomponent',

    config: {
        formFactor: 1
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var me = this;
        var onResize = function() {
            var formFactor = me.getFormFactor();
            var width = me.element.dom.offsetWidth;
            me.setHeight(width/formFactor);                                
        }
        this.on('resize', onResize);
    }

});
```

A Fiddle using it: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/64j

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hbox layout on the parent and specify the flex or width of the container. This will take care of height http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/docs/Ext.layout.HBox.2/